# Ubuntu KVM Guests going Read Only

Tags: kvm-virtualization, ubuntu-14.04

I have three servers, all running KVM with 4-5 Ubuntu Server guests:

1. generic PC, single SATA HDD, Ubuntu 14.04
2. PowerEdge 2950 8GB RAM, 2x SAS 10k in RAID1, Ubuntu 12.04
3. PowerEdge 2950 8GB RAM, 2x SAS 10k in RAID1, Ubuntu 14.04

Server #1 has no issues. Servers #2 & #3 however, are occasionally having guests go 'read only file system'. The guests can be recovered without issue in all except one case, but I am unable to figure out the cause.

The PE's both have PERC 6/i, firmwares are up to date, brand new drives this year. #2 was running fine since January, #3 was added a couple months later, but got light usage until recently. The issue started around a month ago.

They aren't running Dell drives. #2 has 2xWestern Digital WD3001BKHG-02D22, and #3 has 2xHitatchi HUC106060CSS600.

Smart status for both systems comes up clean. Dell diagnostics are also clean.

The guests are running on virtio, RAW disk format. They are not heavy loads. a couple dns servers, and couple light web servers, cacti, etc.

I have moved all the important guests to #1, and #3 is empty except for two testing guests. I had the testing guests running 'stress -d 2' overnight, in an attempt to cause the read only problem, but nothing happened.

I've also run disk performance tests:

```
Host:
Timing cached reads:   12190 MB in  2.00 seconds = 6100.67 MB/sec
Timing buffered disk reads: 480 MB in  3.01 seconds = 159.43 MB/sec

time dd if=/dev/zero of=./file.out bs=1M count=10k
10240+0 records in
10240+0 records out
10737418240 bytes (11 GB) copied, 72.2636 s, 149 MB/s

real    1m12.280s
user    0m0.019s
sys     0m13.268s

Guest:
Timing cached reads:   12434 MB in  2.00 seconds = 6222.50 MB/sec
Timing buffered disk reads: 358 MB in  3.01 seconds = 118.90 MB/sec

time dd if=/dev/zero of=./file.out bs=1M count=10k
10240+0 records in
10240+0 records out
10737418240 bytes (11 GB) copied, 70.4251 s, 152 MB/s

real    1m10.804s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m14.792s
```

I can't find anything in the logs of either the affected guests or the hosts to indicate the cause, and I'm at a loss.

Edit:

Here are some sample OMSA logs:

```
2243    Wed Sep 24 00:23:45 2014    Storage Service The Patrol Read has stopped.: Controller 0 (PERC 6/i Integrated)    
2242    Tue Sep 23 20:08:56 2014    Storage Service The Patrol Read has started.: Controller 0 (PERC 6/i Integrated)    
2334    Tue Sep 23 15:54:55 2014    Storage Service Controller event log: Unexpected sense: PD 01(e0x20/s1) Path 5000cca03c5880d1, CDB: 12 01 dc 01 1d 00, Sense: 5/24/00: Controller 0 (PERC 6/i Integrated)   
2334    Tue Sep 23 15:54:55 2014    Storage Service Controller event log: Unexpected sense: Encl PD 20 Path 50022090b0c9d900, CDB: 12 00 00 00 04 00, Sense: 5/24/00: Controller 0 (PERC 6/i Integrated)    
2334    Tue Sep 23 15:54:55 2014    Storage Service Controller event log: Unexpected sense: Encl PD 20 Path 50022090b0c9d900, CDB: 12 00 00 00 04 00, Sense: 5/24/00: Controller 0 (PERC 6/i Integrated)    
2334    Tue Sep 23 15:54:54 2014    Storage Service Controller event log: Battery temperature is normal: Controller 0 (PERC 6/i Integrated)     
2334    Tue Sep 23 15:54:54 2014    Storage Service Controller event log: Current capacity of the battery is above threshold: Controller 0 (PERC 6/i Integrated)    
2334    Tue Sep 23 15:54:54 2014    Storage Service Controller event log: Battery charge complete: Controller 0 (PERC 6/i Integrated)
```

Comment: anything in OMSA storage logs? Having non-native disks on a PERC can cause all kinds of weirdness, because the disk firmware isn't tested to work well with the controller firmware, causing slow response at times and SCSI timeouts  when things really go downhill. Your VMs will get their disks set to r/o if there's an IO error, if the IO error is severe, the VM might get paused by QEMU. Besides, you are also running Ubuntu as KVM hosts, the amount of QA in the distro is miniscule. I'd try CentOS or Fedora on one of the hosts

Comment: Thanks @dyasny. I've added some sample logs to my question. For new drives, is "Dell Compatible" ok, or do they have to be actual Dell drives? I noticed that there is Dell firmware available for my Hitatchi drives, will that work?

I will also try out CentOS.

Comment: Better call Dell, though I can easily predict them saying only Dell branded drives are supported. The 2950's are pretty old too, who knows what bugs PERC6 has - it hadn't seen an update in years